# Spark Streaming with wholeTextFiles

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using Spark 2.0 and trying to stream files with wholeTextFiles API. My Spark program is reading files successfully the first batch of files in folder, but i can't stream the later batch of files..

Please let me know how do i stream files while using WholeTextFiles API.

Here is my code:

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("My app")
                           .setMaster("local")
                            .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");

JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(15));

JavaPairRDD<String, String> WholeTextLocalFiles = jssc.sparkContext().wholeTextFiles("C:/Users/my/files/abcd7/simple/*.txt");

JavaRDD<String> stringRDD = wholeTextFiles.map(
    -----
    ----
    return mySchema;);

SQLContext hc = new HiveContext(jssc.sparkContext());

Dataset<Row> df = hc.createDataFrame(schemaRDD, mySchema.class);

df.createOrReplaceTempView("myView");

df.show();    
jssc.start();
jssc.awaitTermination();
```

**Spark is processing the data for the first batch. But not any further batches..I am not using javaDStream here, that might be causing this error. How do i get javaDStream from the wholetextfiles api??**

UPDATE ERROR:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:554)
    at com.comcast.emm.vodip.WholeTextLocal.WholeTextLocal.main(WholeTextLocal.java:225)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:554)
```

Comment: You didn't start the stream. After whatever you supposed to do with your data, you should start it so sparks actually starts reading and processing data.

Comment: When i added  jssc.start();
      jssc.awaitTermination(); Spark is processing the data for the first batch. But not any further batches..UPDATED the QUESTION with the error i am getting..

Answer (score 0):

wholeTextFile will return an RDD. Unless you perform some action on it, spark will not initiate any operation.

The error "No output operations registered, so nothing to execute" is telling, you have not used​ the streaming context at all.

Check the example in spark documentation on how to write streaming job.

Comment: Even after doing df.show(), job is not streaming. It's processing only first batch, not a streaming job. Could you please give any guidance on this..

Answer (score 0):

According to [spark docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#input-dstreams-and-receivers) you should avoid setting master to `local` or `local[1]` when processing streams since it leaves no core to process the data.

> When running a Spark Streaming program locally, do not use “local” or
>   “local[1]” as the master URL. Either of these means that only one
>   thread will be used for running tasks locally. If you are using an
>   input DStream based on a receiver (e.g. sockets, Kafka, Flume, etc.),
>   then the single thread will be used to run the receiver, leaving no
>   thread for processing the received data. Hence, when running locally,
>   always use “local[n]” as the master URL, where n > number of receivers
>   to run (see Spark Properties for information on how to set the
>   master).